# Selecting attributes from SSRS XML data source

Tags: xml, reporting-services

I have the folloing XML file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <root>
          <NB>
            <Company>Company 1</Company>
            <Rank Indicator="increasing">2</Rank>
            <Position Indicator="decreasing">1</Rank>
          </NB>
          <NB>
            <Company>Company 2</Company>
            <Rank Indicator="decreasing">42</Rank>
            <Position Indicator="increasing">6</Rank>
          </NB>
    </root>
```

What I need to do is create a dataset which outputs the following columns:

- Company
- RankIndicator
- PositionIndicator

I tried something like this:

```
    <Query>
        <ElementPath>root/ {}/NB</ElementPath>
    </Query>
```

However, this does not include any attributes. I managed to get one attribute by using something like this:

```
    <Query>
        <ElementPath>root/ {}/NB/Rank{@Indicator}</ElementPath>
    </Query>
```

However, I need both Rank and Position indicators and I'm not sure how to provide a list of attributes in this case.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using XML as your datasource?

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing, however I can't figure out how to write the query expression to get what I need.

Comment: Ok, I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood your comment, you must create a data source with no connection string and a new dataset with your XML content as the query string.

This is what you should do:

1. Create an XML data source with a blank connection string.
2. Create a new dataset for the XML data source.
3. In the Dataset Properties dialog box, click Query Designer. The text-based query designer dialog box opens.
4. In the query pane, enter the following:`<Query><XmlData>`
5. Copy your XML file and paste the text in the query pane after `<XmlData>`.
6. Be sure to remove `<?xml version="1.0"?>`
7. At the end of the query, add the following:     `</XmlData></Query>`
8. Click Run Query (!).

In your case your code would be like this:

```
<Query>
    <XmlData>
        <root>
            <NB>
                <Company>Company 1</Company>
                <Rank Indicator="increasing">2</Rank>
                <Position Indicator="decreasing">1</Rank>
            </NB>
            <NB>
                <Company>Company 2</Company>
                <Rank Indicator="decreasing">42</Rank>
                <Position Indicator="increasing">6</Rank>
            </NB>
        </root>
    </XmlData>
</Query>
```

If you want to specify parameters:

```
    </XmlData>
    <ElementPath>YourField {@}</ElementPath>
</Query>
```

**EDIT**

Based on your comment, to retrieve specific fields:

`{FieldA, FieldB, FieldC}`

Sources:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms365158.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345251.aspx

Comment: OK, I see I was misunderstood. I already have an XML data source and dataset. My problem is that I don't know how to write ElementPath expression in the query to get the data I need. Namely the problem is that I can't figure out how to get both Indicator attributes from Rank and Position nodes. I can get one of them no problem, but I can't figure out how to get both of them in the same query.

Comment: Just use comma `,` to add more fields: `{@Id(Integer), @IdXpto(Integer), @FieldD, @FooA, @FooB}`. Didn't that work for you?

Comment: Excellent, that's exactly what I was after. Final query:

root/{}/NB{Company,Rank{@Indicator},Position{@Indicator}}

Comment: Thanks. this answered how I can use XML 'file' in SRSS and then basic query. :) Great answer.

Comment: in point 4 how can i pick xml file dynamically from server location, as i have multiple xml files and i have to pick one on certain conditions